# HTML5 video tag unreliable on iOS

Tags: ios, html5-video

I'm using PhoneGap to make an iPhone app that contains video. Usually, it works great: the video sits in an HTML5 video tag and it shows the iOS play button and then plays full screen.

But, sometimes the play button has a line through it and the user can't play the video.

I can't seen to figure out exactly what causes this, as it is sporadic and doesn't seem to be connected to any other issues.

Any help on making this more reliable would be appreciated. The code is a very simple video tag with src, poster, width and height attributes.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Where do the videos come from?  YouTube?  A lot of YouTube videos are flagged as not playable on mobile.

Comment: They are mp4's loaded from a server. And they work sometimes, so I don't think it's a compression/codec issue.

Comment: Can you somehow see what the server responds in this case? Some kind of 40x? Also, are you streaming your files or is it a plain file?

Comment: It's a plain file. I was able to fix it by reducing the resolution. Now the video plays consistently on iPhone and iPad. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to fix this by exporting video from Quicktime as "iPod touch & iPhone 3GS" instead of "iPad, iPhone 4 & Apple TV." Looks like the HTML5 video tag on iPhone's require a lower resolution to play.